# XCode toolchain: how to move an App from one accounts to another?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, account, toolchain

Similar to [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676961/two-ios-developer-licenses-on-one-mac?rq=1) [*].

Follow up clarification please, as I'm in a parallel universe:

- A. ***Me***, as single Apple Developer.

and

- B. ***Client***, with team of two - I was just added as person 2, an Admin

  (NOT the Agent - he's person 1).

Client gives me source code for an *** App rewrite/fix. *** First version is still live on App store, my upgrade is to be its replacement.

I did the App rewrite on my machine, *using my Apple dev account* and my developer certs for device testing.  So, at this point, it appears to be "my" app. Note, I do not yet have distribution nor iTunes Connect for me OR client.  But THEY do have them for the earlier release of the App, which my upgrade is to replace, as mentioned. )

Now, it's bug-free :-/ and needs to ***go live under the client's account, not mine.***

Here's where I'm stuck and befuddled. (I talked with Apple, and they were somewhat helpful, but I'm concerned about corrupting / conflating all the certs / accounts on my machine.)

Questions:

1a. Can Client just use the portal (under their id) to generate new distribution certs / provisions for me to use ?

1b. and I should put those into MY XCODE ?

"2." Then I can distribute under their account ?

3a. Must they also generate (from their account) a developers cert too for me ? (Two people at Apple suggested so, but weren't sure.)

3b. In which case, must I recompile under their dev cert on my machine, before doing their distribution?

This seems almost Rocket Science difficult, but it shouldn't be !

Thanks for *any* assistance.

( I hope this really does qualify as a programming question according to FAQ item 3 "tool chain" !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either share the client's distribution cert or re-generate a new one.

For the latter case, the client can't distribute the app anymore. You can google it for the first solution, there are heaps.

Comment: yibuyiq, thanks for the prompt reply ! Latter case is not an option, former case is way to go. Odd, I did tons of searches and found nothing. **What search string** did you Google for ?

Comment: thanks - looks pretty messy. Is there a way to do that if I have their account info (I mean, not have to 'go to their machine' to export the stuff ?)

Comment: A follow up - though I appreciate the link, yibuyiqu, the method described there won't work in my case.  Any other suggestions would help. (I have a feeling this is much easier than I think !)

Comment: You should ask your client to export the key and the password to you. It works in my case. which step you are stuck? You can search "ios share distribution certificate" on google.

Comment: the export the key part is where I'm stuck - as far as I can tell, that step (exporting the key) has to be done physically on the machine the "Agent" used to create the account, right? (Or are we talking about just "downloading" the certificate from their account profile ? In which case, I could do that on my machine, but logged in under their account ?) To me, the docs you mention are unclear about this.

Comment: It need to export the key physically on the client's machine.

Comment: Yes, this is correct - Thank You, yibuyiqu ! I'll post a complete answer to my own question later ...